TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object when passing a class function
I am submitting executors from a ProcessPoolExecutor inside my class by passing a class method:
class BackwardEnrichmentService:
    def __init__(
        self,
        ...
    ) -> None:
        ...

    async def enrich_claim(self, claim_number: str) -> bool:
        ...

        futures = []
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(mp_context=mp.get_context('spawn')) as executor:
            futures = [
                executor.submit(
                    self._enrich_peril,
                )
                for key in indicators_dict
            ]

        for f in as_completed(futures):
            indicator_results.append(f.result())

        return all(indicator_results)

    def _enrich_peril(
        self,
    ) -> bool:
        
        return True

As long the passed function is not from my class the executor works correctly without throwing.
Any clues?
